# Как передать json в html через model в Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть метод ,который возвращает страницу с заданиями:

```
 @RequestMapping({"/task"})
public String getTask(Model model......
```

я передаю через Model свой json

```
model.addAttribute("json", InformationModel.getJSON());
```

....

```
return "task";
```

но когда я принимаю его в js

```
var json = '[[${json}]]';
```

json приходит не правильными

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как передать через Model json так ,чтобы он пришел в виде:

```
var json = '{"solution": .....и т.д. и т.п.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том ,что я делал вот так:

```
<script>
var json = '[[${object.getJSONString()}]]';
```

А надо делать вот так:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
var json = [[${object.getJSONString()}]];
```

всё уже предусмотренно!